# How to say 'last wednesday'

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am trying to say "last wednesday" in Latin; as in "Last Wednesday I went to the store." I think it might be something along the lines of Praeterita hebdomas, but want to double check this.

Answer (score 3):

It seems an appropriate word is *[proximus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0060:entry=proximus)*. Thus, "Last Wednesday I went [in]to the shop" would be:

> Proximo die Mercurii adii in tabernam

(where, as noted by Joonas, *proximo die* are in the ablative case, meaning a more literal translation would be something like "I went [to X] on last Wednesday", but in English the "on" is usually omitted).

Notice *proximus* is also used to indicate "next", but I think the verb alone indicates it is the past and so it is "last Wednesday" rather than "next Wednesday".

Comment: Strangely enough, in English, many expressions for a time, like "last Wednesday", "Friday", "next month", can function just like an ablative in Latin! I've found this helpful when explaining to native English speakers who Latin's ablative case works: "like that, but for all nouns, and marked with a case."

Comment: For "the store" in your example sentence, what do you think of [_taberna_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/taberna#Latin) or [_mercatus_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mercatus#Latin)?

Comment: Thanks!  this is all quite helpful.

Comment: @BenKovitz _taberna_ looks good, actually. Thanks.

Comment: @BenKovitz For what I can read, "to go to" can be used with "ad + acc", "_ad tabernam_", or in this case, as one is going **into** the shop, with "in + acc". Do you have a strong prior of which is best?

Comment: @luchonacho I'd use *in* for actually going into the store to buy things. If you were planning to hang around in the general area around the shop, then *ad* is more appropriate, but that doesn't seem to be the OP's case.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thanks. I wonder now how one is to differentiate "last wednesday" from "next wednesday" when the phrase has no context. (probably a bit of a useless question anyway). In this case the verb indicated past.

Comment: @luchonacho I do have a good solution to that, but I'd rather if you asked a separate question. The issue with *proximus* pointing both ways in time deserves more than a comment.